# Efeito de rolagem com Parallax usando vídeo

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax

Eu estou estudando sobre efeitos com Parallax e estou tentando exibir um vídeo no background ao invés de uma imagem. Sendo assim, eu consegui criar um bom efeito usando imagem como background.

Aqui está o meu código **jQuery**:

```js
$('[data-parallax]').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this),
      $window = $(window);

  $window.scroll(function() {
    var y = -($window.scrollTop() / $this.data('speed')),
        background = '50% '+ y + 'px';

    $this.css('background-position', background);
  }); 
});
```

E meu **CSS**:

```css
[data-parallax] {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/720/480');
  background-position: 50% 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

**Exemplo:** http://jsfiddle.net/7a2ky/show/
**Código:** http://jsfiddle.net/7a2ky/

Eu gostaria de fazer o mesmo efeito, mas utilizando [um vídeo](https://showbox-tr.dropbox.com/transcode_video/t/1qz2fy47wt9ay7i/header_background.mp4) ao invés de uma imagem. Isso é possível?

Comment: É possível, mas você não vai poder usar css background pra isso. Vai ter que criar um elemento vídeo, fixa-lo e move-lo pela tela. Recomendo que esteja no início do seu HTML, logo próximo ao `body`, assim não vai ter que mudar o `z-index` pois os outros elementos estarão na frente dele.

Comment: @GabrielGartz, obrigado. Eu cheguei até a fazer isso, mas eu não consegui replicar algumas propriedades específicas do background e essenciais para o funcionamento como `background-position: 50% 0` e `background-size: cover`. Você tem alguma ideia de como isso possa ser feito?

Comment: Se você deixar o vídeo do tamanho da tela ou do tamanho desejado, você pode deixar a área do vídeo no máximo que vai ocupar a tela e usar o css `transform` pra obter o efeito de `cover`, calculando a proporção original pras dimensões de largura e altura do elemento, assim como seu posicionamento. Mas não é tão fácil quanto fazer com `background` pois não tem "atalhos" em enumerados ainda.

Comment: Acho que estou quase lá, @GabrielGartz. Você tem alguma ideia ou exemplo de utilização da propriedade `transform` para este fim?

Comment: Usei `z-index` pra fins de agilidade no dev, mas da pra melhorar, seguinte, vc pode usar o `transform` `scale()` pra atingir a sua proporção no mais é muito parecido, olha o [exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/7a2ky/11/).

Answer (score 3):

Já que não existe uma propriedade específica para background de vídeo em CSS, improvisei uma solução usando o tag `<video>` e um CSS que simula um background. Posicionando com `absolute`, e aplicando um `z-index` bem baixo, o vídeo "flutua abaixo" dos outros itens.

EDIT: Nova versão melhorada: http://jsfiddle.net/ra3qA/11/

(Versão antiga: http://jsfiddle.net/ra3qA/2/)

Um detalhe: enquanto o vídeo não carrega, a tela fica preta. Seria legal corrigir isso de alguma forma. =)

Comment: Obrigado, sua solução é quase perfeita. O problema está na propriedade `background-size: cover`, veja no meu exemplo o que acontece com a imagem quando a área do navegador é menor e compare com o seu. Eu realmente não tenho ideia de como simular essa propriedade para um elemento.

Comment: Agora acho que está certo: http://jsfiddle.net/ra3qA/7/show/

Comment: Eu adicionei um "min-width" que estava faltando. Também coloquei um plugin chamado fitVids que ajuda a posicionar melhor o elemento (mas acho que ele nem é tão necessário nesse caso).

Comment: É, essa versão sem plugin (http://jsfiddle.net/ra3qA/8/show/) tem o mesmo resultado para mim.

Comment: Para o cenário da tela em preto devido à espera até o vídeo esteja carregado, podes utilizar [o atributo `poster`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) que permite fornecer uma imagem a ser apresentada até que o vídeo esteja totalmente carregado, altura em que a primeira frame do mesmo vai passar para o `poster`.

Comment: Em telas menores, a sua versão atualizada não fica centralizada. Diminua o tamanho do navegador para ver. :S

Comment: Desculpe a demora! É, realmente, ele reduz o vídeo... Acho que a solução está em controlar totalmente as dimensões do vídeo por javascript mesmo. Achei uma solução que pode ser interessante. É esse comportamento que você espera? Dá uma olhada no demo: http://www.inserthtml.com/2013/09/quick-tips-background-videos/